# Should h1 - h6 tags always be used sequentially, or are the numbers arbitrary?

Tags: html

I am wondering whether the `h1` - `h6` tags should always be used sequentially (ie, always start with `h1` and for each nested subheading use the adjacent `hx` tag), or whether as long as the order is correct it's ok (eg, starting at `h2` and jumping straight to `h4` is ok).

Comment: Technically, order not required. Semantically, if you can it's better to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 spec says

> [**4.3.10 Headings and sections**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections)
>
> The [`h1`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)–[`h6`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) elements are headings.
>
> The first element of [heading content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#heading-content-0) in an element of [sectioning
>   content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) [represents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) the heading for that section. Subsequent headings
>   of equal or higher [rank](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank) start new (implied) sections, headings of
>   lower [rank](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank) start implied subsections that are part of the previous
>   one. In both cases, the element [represents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) the heading of the implied
>   section. [...]
>
> Sections may contain headings of any [rank](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank), and authors are strongly
>   encouraged to use headings of the appropriate [rank](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank) for the section's
>   nesting level.

Answer (score 0):

Header tags should be used in order of importance in relation to your content.

Thinking of a generic eCommerce site you might want to follow the following structure:

**h1** tags used for the category name or page name

**h2** tags used for each item name listed under the category

**h3** tags used for each item description

Header tags are used mostly to encourage SEO / site crawlers to place importance on specific content in order of h1 - h6.  In general (not always true) h4 - h6 tags do not have as big of an impact compared to h1-h3.

> I am wondering whether the h1 - h6 tags should always be used sequentially (ie, always start with h1 and for each nested subheading use the adjacent hx tag

Header tags should never be nested in each other e.g. `<h1>content<h2>more content</h2></h1>`.  They should always be separate from each other.

> or whether as long as the order is correct it's ok (eg, starting at h2 and jumping straight to h4 is ok).

Jumping from h2 to h4 is ok and using a h4 before h2 is ok so long as your content dictates that it is ok.